# Using WHERE IN with prepared SQL statements in Propel

Tags: php, select, propel

In a system I'm working on that uses Propel for handling the database, I'm preparing a raw query that needs to accept a varying WHERE IN condition.

A simple example what I'm trying to do is this:

```
$c = Propel::getConnection();
$q = $c->prepare("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE blah IN(:ids)");
$q->execute(array(':ids' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
```

Obviously, this isn't working for me.  I've also tried using implode(',' array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) as my ':ids' parameter, which also doesn't work.  The first method complains of having to accept an array, and the second method complains of comparing a string to an integer.

Is there a proper way to pass an array of values to a query for a WHERE IN?  I don't want to hard code it, as that would mean preparing it for every iteration of a loop.

Note that I don't really have the option of creating a criteria and using doSelect instead, as the query is actually far more complicated than the example given here and I seriously doubt I could build it that way.

Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry - postgresql.  Thanks for all the answers folks!  That steered me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement. You cannot bind multiple values to a single named parameter in, for example, the IN() clause of an SQL statement.

[PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php)

> Propel uses PDO

[Propel site](http://www.propelorm.org/)

Answer (score 2):

This is the PDO Workaround:

```
$yourListOfIDs = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

$q = $c->prepare("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE blah IN(".rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($yourListOfIDs)), ',').")");

// bindValue starts at 1 (not 0)
foreach ($yourListOfIDs as $key => $val)
{
  $q->bindValue(($key+1), $val);
}

$q->execute();
```

Beware: code not tested

Answer (score 2):

If the DB you use is MySQL then perhaps using a query like:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE FIND_IN_SET(blah, :ids) > 0
```

would work. You have to use `implode(',', array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))` for the parameter value in this case. If the `blah` is of `int` type then you might have to cast it to `char`, like `FIND_IN_SET(CAST(blah AS CHAR), :ids)`

Comment: You were missing a comma so I fixed it.